# Does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' while calling async method

Tags: c#, async-await

I am getting the *compiler error*

> CS1061  'MAUserVM' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and
> no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument
> of type 'MAUserVM' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly reference?)

**Async Method**

```
public class MAUserVM
{
    public string AuthenticationStatus;

    public MAUser mAUser;

    public async Task<MAUserVM> GetMAUserAsync(string Email, string Password, IConfiguration configuration, IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Calling method**

```
private async Task<Boolean> AuthenticateUser(string email, string password)
{
    ...

    // exception happening here
    userVM = await userVM.GetMAUserAsync(email, password, _configuration, _accessor).Result;

    ...
}
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The fix**

```
//userVM = await userVM.GetMAUserAsync(email, password, _configuration, _accessor).Result;
userVM = await userVM.GetMAUserAsync(email, password, _configuration, _accessor);
```

---

**The short story**

You are calling `Result` on a `Task` which returns the `T` (aka `MAUserVM`), then trying to `await` it.

---

**The long story**

You can `await` any *instance* that exposes `GetAwaiter` (either as an instance method or extension method). A `GetAwaiter` needs to implement the `INotifyCompletion` interface (and optionally the `ICriticalNotifyCompletion` interface) and return a type that itself exposes several members. `Task` is one such object that implements the above (which is why you can `await` it)

The *compiler error* is telling you `MAUserVM` does not have the `GetAwaiter` method because you had already retrieved it (the *result*) from the `Task` using the [`Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netcore-3.1) method.

> Gets the result value of this `Task<TResult>`.

**Further more**

In *modern .Net*, If you ever find your self calling `Result`, `Wait` or similar *hackery*, always think to yourself there is a better way, and that way is
usually just call `await`. If you ignore this advice you will likely be *blocking* on an *async method* and find yourself with *deadlocks*, convoluted *aggregate exceptions*, or hard to *debug* issues.

---

**Additional Resources**

[Stephen Cleary - Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)